# Detect when there is no barcode recognized by VNDetectBarcodesRequest

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, barcode-scanner, avcapturesession

I am making an app that recognises QR Barcodes on the live camera (not still images). I wanted to highlight the code when it is detected and this I am achieving already. What I can't do is remove the highlight layer from the screen when the QR Code stops appearing on the live camera. Is there a callback like from `VNDetectBarcodesRequest` called when it could not find any barcode on the PixelBuffer?

Here is my code:

```swift
private class VideoDataOutputDelegate: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
            
            let session: AVCaptureSession
            let error: (Error) -> ()
            let qrCodeReading: (VNBarcodeObservation) -> ()
            var detectBarcodeRequest: VNDetectBarcodesRequest {
                VNDetectBarcodesRequest(completionHandler: processClassification)
            }
            
            init(session: AVCaptureSession, error: @escaping (Error) -> (), qrCodeReading: @escaping (VNBarcodeObservation) -> ()) {
                
                self.session = session
                self.error = error
                self.qrCodeReading = qrCodeReading
                
            }
            
            func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
                guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
                    return
                }
                
                let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(
                    cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer,
                    orientation: .right)
                
                do {
                    try imageRequestHandler.perform([detectBarcodeRequest])
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            
// Here I get the barcode when it appears. But how to track when it disappears?

            func processClassification(_ request: VNRequest, _ error: Error?) {
                guard error == nil, let barcodes = request.results else {
                    //never printed
                    print("no barcode 2")
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                    if session.isRunning {
                        
                        for barcode in barcodes {
                            guard
                                
                                let potentialQRCode = barcode as? VNBarcodeObservation
                            else {
                                print("no barcode")
                                return
                            }

                            self.qrCodeReading(potentialQRCode)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
```

Thank you a lot!